# Getting the current month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

In an SQL query I need to get some data only from the current month. To get a specific month, I would do this.

```
select (case when date_part('month', date) = 3 and date_part('year', date) = 2014 then amount end)
       ,(case when date_part('month', date) = 3 and date_part('year', date) = 2013 then amount end
from <table>
```

My main purpose is to get the current month for this year, and the same month from the previous year.

This is what I would try

```
select current_month(case when date_part('year', date) = 2014 then amount end) as current
       ,(case when current_month and date_part('year', date) = 2013 then amount end) as last_year
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to your intent here, are you looking for a modification to your quert where instead of 3, 2014 and 2013, those values are being used based on the current date dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I want to put like a 'current_month' type thing, so I'll add that.

Comment: can't you just use date_part again for current_timestamp? instead of the 3 and year? `date_part('Year',current_Timestamp)` `date_part('Month', current_Timestmap)`

Comment: @xQbert the problem is I don't know how to do that.

Comment: A question like this *needs* a table definition. The best solution depends on the data types in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `now()` or `current_timestamp` to get the current time, then the current month, year, and last year:

```
select (case when date_part('month', date) = extract(month from now()) and date_part('year', date) = extract(year from now()) then amount end)
       ,(case when date_part('month', date) = extract(month from now()) and date_part('year', date) = extract(year from now())-1 then amount end
from <table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using comment feedback:

```
select (case when date_part('month', date) = date_part('month',current_Timestamp) and 
        date_part('year', date) = date_part('Year',current_TimeStamp) then amount end)
       ,(case when date_part('month', date) = date_part('month',current_Timestamp) and 
        date_part('year', date) = date_part('Year',current_TimeStamp)-1 then amount end
from <table>
```

and example fiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e495f/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL code so you can get the current month and year

```
 select DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())
 select DATEPART(YY,GETDATE())
```

So your full code would be:

```
select (case when DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) = 3 and DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) = 2014 then amount end)
   ,(case when DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) = 3 and DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) = 2013 then amount end
from <table>
```